# Excel VBA: Creating folders when user clicks on a cell

Tags: excel, vba

i am using this vba code to create a folder when the user clicks on a cell. it pulls the new folder name from a cell value. this works fine but now what i want to try and do is create a parent folder with only the month of todays date and the year.

so imagine we want to create two new folders in our directory. 
our directory is

```
"Z:\Files\Storage\"
```

we want to create a folder firstly with today's month and year from todays date like so

```
Aug 2014
```

then we want to create the second folder inside Aug 2014 folder with the value in my cell, lets say this is called

```
medical
```

we should have a directory which looks like this:

"Z:\Files\Storage\Aug 2014\medical"

here's what i've tried

```
If Target.Column = Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Column Then
  If Target.Row > 7 Then

'Variable definations
Dim FolderListRange As Range
Dim FolderRange As Variant
Dim FolderName As String
Dim ParentFolderPath As String

On Error GoTo Handle
    ' Set the Folder where the individual folders should be created
    ParentFolderPath = "\\UKSH000-FILE06\purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups"


    Set FolderListRange = Date & Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    For Each FolderRange In FolderListRange

        FolderName = ParentFolderPath & "\" & Date & FolderRange.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row)

        If FileSystem.Dir(FolderName) = vbNullString Then
            FileSystem.MkDir FolderName
        End If


Continue:
    Next

Handle:
  End If
  End If
```

its not creating the folders can someone please show me where im going wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the problem...?

Comment: And what is the error? Where is it crashing?  Is it not creating the folder you expected?  what is your question about the code?

Comment: @Jan have added the problem, its not creating the folders and i am gettin no error

Comment: This is because you handle the errors. Of course you can't see the error. Remove it and tell us the error.

Comment: @Jan it gives me a run time error 424 - object required

Comment: On which line does the error occure?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, your error is in the following line:

```
Set FolderListRange = Date & Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

A range and a date are not compatible types.